# remove error message in javascript in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a text input field `serial number` and a toggle button.`serial number` is required by default. So, if `serial number` is left blank then it will display error message.
But,If the toggle button is checked then error message from `serial number` should be removed. But it continues to display the error message.

`html`

```
<template>
<lightning-input class="serialnumber" label ="serial 
  number" name="serialnumber" onchange= {handleChange} required={isRequired}
                          message-when-value-missing="serial Number is req">
</lightning-input>
  <!--toggle html>
  <label class="slds-checkbox_toggle slds-truncate"> 
  <input type="checkbox" name="infoToggle" checked={infoToggleValue} 
                                           onchange={handleChange} />
  <span class="slds-checkbox_on slds-text-body_small">not required</span>
  <span class="slds-checkbox_off slds-text-body_small">required</span>
  </label>
</template>
```

`js`

```
import { LightningElement, track} from 'lwc';
export default class CmpInputScreen extends LightningElement {

@track serialNumber;
@track infoToggleValue = false;
get isRequired(){
    if(this.infoToggleValue){
        return false;
    } return true;
}
handleChange(event) {
    const inputName = event.target.name;
    if (inputName === 'serialnumber') {
        this.serialNumber= event.target.value;
    }else if(inputName === 'infoToggle'){
        //it gets set to true when checked and isRequired sets to false
        this.infoToggleValue = event.target.checked; 
        if(this.infoToggleValue){
           let inputEle = this.template.querySelector('.serialnumber');
            inputEle.setCustomValidity("");
            inputEle.reportValidity();
          }
        }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a matter of asynchronous rendering. When you update the value of `this.infoToggleValue`, you need to allow some time for the `isRequired` expression to get re-evaluated in your template before reporting validity.

You need to wrap your call to `reportValidity` in a resolved Promise to let the framework do a rerender in the meantime.

```js
handleChange(event) {
    const inputName = event.target.name;
    if (inputName === 'serialnumber') {
        this.serialNumber = event.target.value;
    } else if (inputName === 'infoToggle') {
        //it gets set to true when checked and isRequired sets to false
        this.infoToggleValue = event.target.checked;
    }
    // Revalidate serial number
    Promise.resolve().then(() => {
        const inputEle = this.template.querySelector('.serialnumber');
        inputEle.reportValidity();
    });
}
```

**Edit:** force revalidation of serial number in all cases.

Comment: I was able to remove error message with your solution and I was also able to add error message in the similar way, when toggle is uncheked back again. However, at this point, when i put some value in the text field, it should have removed the error message since it is not longer blank. But it still displayed error message

Comment: Updated my answer to deal with that.

Answer (score 1):

`required` attribute doesn't work like you use it. It doesn't get a value of true or false.
If the `required` attribute exists in the tag the input is already required. So if you want to change it you must delete the `required`attribute from the element, e.g. like below:

```
this.template.querySelector('.serialnumber').removeAttribute('required');
```

Comment: Great answer! It works for me! Thanks Jakub.

Comment: @Jakub, I tried this solution but it did not remove error message.